# MySql query to select records with a particular date

Tags: mysql, datetime

so right now I'm storing a the date of each search done on my site like this

```
2011-06-07 21:44:01
```

now I'd like to execute a query to select all values where the date is equal to whatever, but only the year / month and day are taken into account, so it would be like

```
mysql_query("SELECT tag from tags WHERE date = '2011-06-07'");
```

but it shouldn't  take into account the exact time (hour minute seconds), is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

```
SELECT `tag`
  FROM `tags`
 WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2011-06-07'
```

However, for better performance you could use...

```
  WHERE `date` 
BETWEEN '2011-06-07'
    AND '2011-06-07 23:59:59'
```

Comment: @CleverQuack Using `DATE()` causes a fullscan.

Comment: It is better performance, but it is possibly incorrect.  DATETIME and TIMESTAMP allow fractional seconds, so a time a DATETIME of "2011-06-07 23:59:59.5" would be omitted from the second example.  Perhaps better would be WHERE '2011-06-07 <= `date` AND `date` < '2011-06-08'. Or you could just assume that no dates have fractional seconds, which is almost certainly true (almost always).

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
mysql_query("SELECT tag from tags WHERE date LIKE '2011-06-07%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT tag from tags WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2011-06-07'");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: There are performance implications of using this method; see Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer am about to post is long overdue but it can help someone who may experience the same problem.

For my case I used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE dateCol >= date("2017-11-01") 
AND dateCol < date("2017-11-01") + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Its faster than using DATE() function.

If you are using a stored procedure, you could pass in the date as a string and supply it as an argument in place of `("2017-11-01")`