# MySQL select between two dates not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, join, date, between

I'm trying to create a query that will select all dates between two dates
This is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM D1,D2
    WHERE D1.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' AND D1.D1_ID = D2.D2_ID";
```

The trouble is, it is not returning anything, but not producing an error either

So I tried inputting it directly into phpMyAdmin like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM D1,D2
    WHERE D1.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-12'
        AND D1.D1_ID = D2.D2_ID`
```

then like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM D1,D2
    WHERE D1.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-12'
```

and like this

```
SELECT * FROM D1
    WHERE DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-12'
```

and I just get

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )

Yes, my tables exist, and so do the columns :)

Comment: And you have data that has a `DATE_ADDED` that's between 1-Jan-2011 and 12-Dec-2011, it's not 2010 data perhaps?

Comment: your code works perfectly, could you possibly supply the table with the dates?

Comment: Could you show us the schema and some sample rows of the 2 tables ?

Comment: working now! changed nothing! extremely confused!

Answer (score 1):

In the first cases the lack of results could be because of the inner join. For a result to be in the set it would require a record in both tables, ie. a record from d1 would not appear unless d2 also had that id in the d2_id column. To resolve this, if that is correct for your business logic, use `left join`.

However, the last of your cases (without the join) suggests the reasons is a lack of matching records in the first (left) table d1.

Without the full dataset we can't really comment further, since all the code you are running is perfectly valid.

Comment: `x BETWEEN a AND b` is equivalent to `(a <= x) AND (x <= b)`

Comment: @ypercube. Quite correct. Momentary aberration there. Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to select an entire year it is easer to select it like this:

`SELECT * FROM D1 WHERE YEAR(DATE_ADDED) = 2011;`

Comment: Easier, yes. Faster, no. Faster is `(DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND 2011-12-31)`

Comment: See the comment on this answer for more info on the performance implications:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273361/select-from-mysql-database-where-day-php/6273368#6273368

Answer (score 0):

Please implement below code

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM D1,D2
    WHERE D1.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2011-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
        AND DATE_FORMAT('2011-12-12','%Y-%m-%d')
        AND D1.D1_ID = D2.D2_ID`
```