# Issues binding value in pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue getting a date bound to a variable in an MySql query I'm trying to make.

I have the following query that works

```
$sql = 'SELECT `date` FROM `sessions` WHERE `date` LIKE "%2022-07-09%"';
```

I need the LIKE portion to be dynamic, I am trying to select 7 days in the past from the current date, to do that I am creating the date in a PHP variable.

```
$lastWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days"));
```

I replaced the hardcoded value in the LIKE portion of my query

```
$sql = 'SELECT `date` FROM `lift_sessions` WHERE `date` LIKE "%:lastweek%"';
```

And then bound the variable to :lastweek

```
$stmt->bindValue(':lastweek', $lastWeek);
```

However when I execute that it doesn't match anything

I've tried making the query a few different ways including adding the % in the PHP variable and removing them from the SQL query. It only seems to work if I hardcode the date into the SQL query. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I feel like it's simple and I just can't see it...

Thanks in advance.

```
public static function compareWeeklyStats() {

    $current_date = date('F, jS');

    $lastWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days"));

    //error_log($lastWeek);

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
        $sql = 'SELECT `date` FROM `sessions` WHERE `date` LIKE "%:lastweek%"';
        $db = static::getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt->bindValue(':user', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        //$stmt->bindValue(':lastweek', $lastWeek);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lastweek', $lastWeek, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        error_log(print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), true));
        return;
    }

    return; }
```

Comment: can you show us the rest of your code, where you prepare the statement etc? is usually much quicker to find the issue if we see all the code that leads to the problem. Also, echo out the date so you can make sure its the exact date you expect. server timezones can mess with things sometimes if you don't set things up a certain way.

Comment: does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068230/using-like-in-bindparam-for-a-mysql-pdo-query

Comment: @dqhendricks I edited my question to include the full function I am using.

Comment: Why do you need like when using dates - do you want to exclude the time part of the field?

Comment: Yes that is correct @NigelRen the entries in the DB look like: 2022-07-09 18:54:00 and I need to match them based on just the date portion, not the time.

Comment: This is what ended up working : $sql = 'SELECT `date` FROM `lift_sessions` WHERE `date` LIKE CONCAT(:lastweek, "%")'; using CONCAT

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273368/1213708, this is probably a better solution.

Comment: @grzybowski1911 the reason your first try did not work is because of the quotes. You don't need quotes around the bind variable. And the % should be in the php variable, but only needed at the end, not both sides. For example: `LIKE :lastweek` where `$lastweek = $date.'%'`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this?

Create the sql with the placeholder

```
$sql = 'SELECT `date` FROM `lift_sessions` WHERE `date` LIKE :lastweek';
```

Create the `like` variable

```
$like='%' . $lastWeek . '%';
```

Then bind the variable containing the wildcard characters

```
$stmt->bindParam(':lastweek', $like );
```

Then execute and process recordset

---

A test of the method described above in light of comment that it does not work...

The db schema

```
mysql> select
    ->      `taskname`,
    ->      `industryname`,
    ->      `country`,
    ->      `orgname`
    ->  from `volopp`;
    
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------------------+
| taskname             | industryname      | country  | orgname                       |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------------------+
| squirrel juggling    | outdoor pursuits  | scotland | Squirrel Jugglers Association |
| Hedgehog Pickling    | food and drink    | england  | Hog Heaven Association        |
| Haggis Hunting       | outdoor pursuits  | scotland | Campbell's Haggis Hunt        |
| Nessie Netting       | outdoor pursuits  | scotland | NessieNets.org.uk             |
| Dwarf Tossing        | outdoor pursuits  | scotland | highlandgames.scot            |
| Stickleback Stuffing | indoor pursuits   | wales    | stickleback.org               |
| squirrel suckling    | historic pastimes | ireland  | weirdness abounds             |
+----------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------------------+


mysql> describe volopp;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| taskname     | varchar(50)         | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| industryname | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| description  | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country      | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| orgname      | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| photo        | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status       | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then, in PHP:

```
$var='squirr';

$sql='select 
    `taskname`,
    `industryname`,
    `country`,
    `orgname` 
from `volopp` 
    where `taskname` like :taskname';
    
$like='%' . $var . '%';

$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam(':taskname', $like );
$stmt->execute();

printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ), true ) );
```

Yields the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [taskname] => squirrel juggling
            [industryname] => outdoor pursuits
            [country] => scotland
            [orgname] => Squirrel Jugglers Association
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [taskname] => squirrel suckling
            [industryname] => historic pastimes
            [country] => ireland
            [orgname] => weirdness abounds
        )

)
```

OK - not using a date as per the question but it should work the same

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by: "I've tried making the query a few different ways including adding the % in the PHP variable and removing them from the SQL query." - that isn't working for me. I'm not sure why as it seems like this should be the solution..

Comment: a simple example test of this worked OK on my system

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing the following line and got it to work as expected: $sql = 'SELECT date FROM sessions WHERE date LIKE CONCAT(:lastweek, "%")'; using CONCAT to add the % and that seemed to work